# Rspec/Rails: uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

I am trying to run `bundle exec rspec` but  am getting the following error that is being thrown in my call to `spec_helper.rb`

```
template.rb:8:in `<class:Template>': uninitialized constant ActiveSupport::Autoload (NameError)
```

Here is my `spec_helper.rb` file:

```
require 'rubygems'
require 'rspec/rails'
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= 'test'
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)   
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
end
```

Comment: the line `require 'rspec/rails'` is getting me into trouble.

Comment: Put that after the config/environment require.

Comment: can you answer the question and close it as answered?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After switching the order of my Rspec file to the following, I no longer get the uninitialized constant error:

```
require File.expand_path("../../config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'
require 'capybara/rspec'
require 'capybara/poltergeist'
Capybara.register_driver :poltergeist do |app|
  Capybara::Poltergeist::Driver.new(app, {:js_errors=> false})
end
RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.infer_spec_type_from_file_location!
```